# Is there a spelling mistake or am I missing something

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions, elementary-functions, rounding-unit

[image: This is from book called inequalities by korovkin]

Here, $[ \cdot]$  is $\lfloor \cdot \rfloor $ floor function.
N $ \in N$. Where did $\frac{[Nx]} N + \frac{1}{2N}$ came from 
and how does $x$ differs by $\frac{1}{2N}$. Shouldn't it be
$\frac{1}N$ if $x$ is an integer.

Comment: fixed @Moo .thanks !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a=\frac{[Nx]}{N}$ and $b= \frac{[Nx]}{N} +\frac{1}{N}$

$\frac{[Nx]}{N} +\frac{1}{2N}=\frac{a+b}{2}$ is the midpoint of $a$ and $b$. By the first sets inequalities, we know that $x$ is between these $a$ and $b$. Thus:

$$a\leq x \leq b$$
$$\implies$$
$$a\leq x \leq \frac{a+b}{2} \mbox{ or } \frac{a+b}{2}\leq x \leq b$$
(This describes the three cases: $x$ is to the right of the midpoint, to the left of the midpoint, or on the midpoint).

In all of these cases, $x$ is not further away from either $a$ or $b$ than their midpoint. And clearly, the midpoint is distance $\frac{1}{2N}$ from either. Thus we get the bound described.

Comment: Thanks for help

Comment: Why did you change which answer you accepted?

Comment: i thought i could accept both answers

Comment: You can always upvote both!!

Comment: to upvote I need at least 15 reputations but I only have 13

Answer (score 1):

The double inequality
$$\frac{\lfloor Nx\rfloor}N \leqslant x \leqslant \frac{\lfloor Nx\rfloor}N + \frac 1N$$
describes an interval containing the $x$ value:
$$x\in\left [ \frac{\lfloor Nx\rfloor}N , \frac{\lfloor Nx\rfloor}N + \frac 1N \right]$$

The interval starts at $\frac{\lfloor Nx\rfloor}N$ and its length is $\frac 1N$, so the value
$$\frac{\lfloor Nx\rfloor}N + \frac 1{2N}$$
is just a midpoint of the interval.

And any $x$ in the interval differs from the interval's midpoint by not more than a half of the interval's length:
$$\left|x - \left(\frac{\lfloor Nx\rfloor}N + \frac 1{2N}\right)\right| \leqslant \frac 1{2N}$$

Comment: Thanks!!! Even though my question was so dumb you answered thanks for that

Comment: @YugantShewale Your question is not 'dumb' :D Everyone was once a beginner, and everyone can misread or misunderstand something. As long as you really try to get through and make a decent effort to explain your problem to get an answer, the question is valid and it deserves explanation and answer.

Comment: Comment to myself re _'Everyone was once a beginner'_ – if you look from an experience level high enough, everyone is _still_ a beginner....